# C++: request for thread member for class, cannot be access

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to write a class include a public thread object, and finally I want to access this thread ouside the class, but there are some errors, why?

The class defined as:

```cpp
class scoped_thread {
public:
    std::thread t;
    explicit scoped_thread(std::thread t_) : t(std::move(t_)) {
        if (!t.joinable()) 
            throw std::logic_error("No thread");

    }

    ~scoped_thread() {
        // t.join();
    }

    scoped_thread(scoped_thread const &) = delete;
    scoped_thread & operator = (scoped_thread const &) = delete;
};
```

and I'm try to access thread member:

```
scoped_thread th(std::thread(f));
th.t.join();
```

At last, the error is:

```
error: request for member 't' in 'th', which is of non-class type 'scoped_thread(std::thread)'
```

Comment: Why would you want to expose that as `public`? Making a `join()` wrapper method would make more sense here.

Comment: of course you are right, I just want to know why I can not access this member outside.

Comment: Is that the complete error or just part of it? How is `th` declared?

Answer (score 3):

`scoped_thread th(std::thread(f));` is a declaration of a function named `th`, returning `scoped_thread` and taking `std::thread` as a parameter. It's not a declaration of an object of type `scoped_thread`. Naturally, the function doesn't have members, named `t` or otherwise.

See also: [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 3):

You've run into the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). C++ thinks you've declared a function named `th` instead of an object. In recent versions of C++, to correct the issue you can use curly braces instead of parentheses.

```cpp
scoped_thread th{std::thread{f}}; // compiles as expected
```